# How to update cells in excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel sheet and wish to edit fields.

With this code I can edit information in the excel file.

This table starts at A1. It won't let me post pictures.  So picture a 3 x 2 matrix.  With City State and Zip as headers in A1, A2, and A3.  Below them  Detroit  Michigan    48307 in B1, B2, and B3.  Can't make it any clearer than this.

```
{
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            string sql = null;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";");
            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

            String mySheet = "Sheet1$";
            String mySET = "State = 'Michigan";
            String myWHERE = "Zip = '48102";
            sql = "UPDATE [" + mySheet + "$] SET " + mySET + "' WHERE " + myWHERE + "'"; 
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
```

Now when I edit this excel file and put in block A1 some text and shift my 3 x 2 matrix down a couple rows..  It no longer works and won't update.  I'm assuming that the code is defaulting to look for those header names in row 1,

IS there a way to tell the code to start searching at a particular row and column for the table of information?

Please do not post or click that this question is already answered or not clear.. This is as clear as I can make it, if it's not clear just ask a question. I've looked for answer to this and haven't found any.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `"UPDATE [" + mySheet + "$A4:C10] SET "...` (substitute the actual range you want to update)

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you for not blasting my question Tim.

Comment: Thank you Tim!!! That Worked!!  How do I give you the green check mark?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"UPDATE [" + mySheet + "$A4:C10] SET "...
```

(substitute the actual range you want to update)